# Proof that $\gcd(2^m-1,2^n+1)=1$ for odd $m$ using group theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, elementary-number-theory, divisibility, gcd-and-lcm

Below is a perfectly fine proof using basic tools of number theory:

[Showing $\gcd(2^m-1,2^n+1)=1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/572248/showing-gcd2m-1-2n1-1)

Could we prove this more quickly using group theory? I would be very interested in seeing an abstract algebra-flavored proof.

Comment: I gave an answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/876013/242) based on group theory. The later answer below by Alex W uses exactly the same argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let $d=\gcd(2^m-1,2^n+1)$ and $\phi:\mathbb Z\to \mathbb{Z}/(d)$ be the natural homomorphism of rings. We will use a bar convention. Since $d\mid 2^m-1$, then $0=\overline{2^m-1}={\bar 2}^m-1$, i.e. $\bar 2^m=1$. Similarly, $\bar 2^n=-1$. It follows, that $\bar 2\in(\mathbb{Z}/(d))^*$, where $(\mathbb{Z}/(d))^*$ - group of invertible elements of $\mathbb{Z}/(d)$. Since $\bar 2^n=-1$, then $\bar 2^{2n}=1$. So, $\bar 2^m=1$ and $\bar 2^{2n}=1$, hence $|\bar 2|\mid m$ and $|\bar 2|\mid 2n$, i.e. $|\bar 2|\mid\gcd(m,2n)$. Since $m$ odd, then $\gcd(m,2n)=\gcd(m,n)$, therefore $\bar 2^m=1$, $\bar 2^n=1$. But $\bar 2^n=-\bar 1$, hence $\bar 1=-\bar 1$. It follows that $\bar 2=0$, i.e. $d\mid 2$. But, obviously, $d$ is odd, hence $d=1$.

Comment: Using similar argument's it can be proved, for example, that $\gcd(a^m-1,a^n-1)=a^{\gcd(m,n)}-1$ for any natural $m,n$ and $a>1$.

Comment: The overline is used to denote congruence classes?

Comment: @StVincent Yes. $\bar x=\phi(x)$.

Comment: I thought $\phi(d)$ was the order of $\mathbb{Z}/(d)?$

Comment: I prefer to denote Euler totient function $\varphi(d)$. Then $\varphi(d)=|(\mathbb Z/(d))^*|$ - order of a group of invertible elements of $\mathbb Z/(d)$.

Comment: @StVincent This answer is an exact duplicate of an older [answer here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/876013/242). Since a moderator has removed the duplicate link I can only mention it in a comment.

Comment: @Bill Dubuque I just heard about your answer for the first time.